# to get unique records from table after join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I hav tables **event**, **session**, **sessionspeaker**, **speaker** and **Employee**
event table has **EventID** as **PK**, **session** table can have **multiple Eventid** and has **sessionid** as **pk**, **speaker** table has **speakerid** as pk and has **empID** column, **employee** table has **empID** as **PK**. **sessionspeaker** table has **(sessionid, speakerid) as pk.** 
Now I wud like to hav all the eventid with Topmost emplID such that the event id is unique

```
SELECT     emp.EmployeeID, e.EventID
FROM    Event AS e INNER JOIN Session ON e.EventID = Session.EventID left outer JOIN
SessionSpeaker ON Session.SessionID = SessionSpeaker.SessionID INNER JOIN
Speaker ON SessionSpeaker.EmployeeID = Speaker.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
Employee AS emp ON Speaker.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
```

this query returns

```
EmployeeID   EventID
5351         310
5351         310
5352         299
5352         300
5352         301
5352         302
5352             303
5352         314
5352         315
```

this is what I don't want, I want unique event ID and topmost employeeID 
Kindly, let me know an easy way to solve this. 
will groupby, having or count help in this matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want unique event ID and topmost employeeID

Just `GROUP BY e.EventID` and select `MAX(EmployeeId)`:

```
SELECT 
  e.EventID, 
  MAX(emp.EmployeeID) AS TopMostEmpId, 
FROM    Event AS e 
INNER JOIN Session         ON e.EventID                 = Session.EventID 
INNER JOIN SessionSpeaker  ON Session.SessionID         = SessionSpeaker.SessionID 
INNER JOIN Speaker         ON SessionSpeaker.EmployeeID = Speaker.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Employee AS emp ON Speaker.EmployeeID        = emp.EmployeeID
GROUP BY e.EventID
```

If you want to select more columns than `eventId`, `employeeId` you can use a ranking function something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
      e.EventID, 
      emp.EmployeeID,
      e.EventName,
      emp.EmployeeName,
      ...
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.EventID 
                        ORDER BY emp.EmployeeId DESC) AS RN
    FROM    Event AS e 
    INNER JOIN Session         ON e.EventID                 = Session.EventID 
    INNER JOIN SessionSpeaker  ON Session.SessionID         = SessionSpeaker.SessionID 
    INNER JOIN Speaker         ON SessionSpeaker.EmployeeID = Speaker.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN Employee AS emp ON Speaker.EmployeeID        = emp.EmployeeID
) 
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks wa Jazakallah ukhair, The first query is ok however the second query eliminates all the record which has RN > 1. However I want the first record for each to be shown whose RN > 1

Comment: @shomaail El 3afo my brother, you are welcome any time :) Yes, the second query eliminates all the records which has `RN > 1`, because I wrote it `WHERE RN = 1`, but why do you want the records which has `RN > `? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As I wrote in the question I want the topmost  employeeID only

Comment: @shomaail - `WHERE RN = 1` should give you the top most `employeeID` only, note that `ORDER BY` should be `DESC` I missed that, see my edit. have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     emp.EmployeeID, distinct e.EventID
FROM    Event AS e INNER JOIN Session ON e.EventID = Session.EventID left outer JOIN
SessionSpeaker ON Session.SessionID = SessionSpeaker.SessionID INNER JOIN
Speaker ON SessionSpeaker.EmployeeID = Speaker.EmployeeID INNER JOIN
Employee AS emp ON Speaker.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID 

group by e.EventID
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Comment: This won't work, you can't use `distinct` this way. Furthermore it won't give the desired results.